# app store distribution provisioning profile from different account than the one to submit to itunes

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, provisioning

I have developed an iphone app for a client. Can I code sign app against the appstore distribution provisioning profile generated from my apple developer account, send it to the client & let him submit it to apple itunes from his apple developer account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i learned from my experience, this is not possible. You need to have the provisioning profile generated from the same developer account which you want to use to publish to the appstore.

Answer (score -1):

Basically yes, but look into the xcode 4 archive organizer. You can share an archive with another Xcode. From there it seems to be possibe to do a re-signing. Since your client must use anyway his xcode for submitting to the AppStore, this might be a way to go.